# How do I return the Ids of all items across all pages in my Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need some help with my Kendo Grid.  I run a function on my grid when the data is bound called `initialSelection`.  The purpose of the function is to select all items in my grid that match Id passed in via an array.

Here is my grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel>()
.Name("CarGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Select().Width(50);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Name");
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("initialSelection"))
.PersistSelection(true)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetVessels", "Test"))
))
```

Here is the code for that function.

```
function initialSelection(e) {
    var arr = [206, 210, 7010, 209],
        grid = e.sender,

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.items().length; i++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(grid.dataItem(grid.items()[i]).Id) > -1) {
            grid.select(grid.items()[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So, this function takes an array (defined in the function for demo purposes), and checks the grid for this Ids, if it finds them it selects that row.  The issue is that the function runs on a page by page basis.  Since I have a lot of data, paging is a must!

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetCars([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var car = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get().OrderBy(i => i.Name);
        var result = car.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I've seen some posts about using `dataSource.data()` but I'm not sure how to implement it.  When I did some testing, it still only showed 10 results which is the default number when paging is enabled.

Does anyone know how I can iterate over all the rows on every page in the grid and return the Ids of those that are selected?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over the rows that aren't visible?

Comment: Is your pagging server-side or client-side?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It's client side.  The controller returns all result, however, paging set on the client side, the result set returned is always 10.  That's why the event triggers one per page because each page requests data from the controller, albeit at a limit of 10.  It's a common problem and I'm surprised Telerik haven't sorted it.

Comment: you are looping into **items**, you should be looping into **data** array, here is an example https://dojo.telerik.com/UNOvUFUT

Comment: Thank you for this example @softawareblog.com the only problem with this approach is it still only returns the first 10 data items on the first page.

Comment: @Yanayaya this is not possible, if you check my provided example you will see *length* has a value of 830

Comment: @softawareblog.com I saw your example and I have the same problem .you know dataSource.data.length() return just 50 but the total is more than 400 records.